# PHP: Foreach Simlplexml output

Tags: php, arrays, xml, foreach

I got a xmlfile exported from the datamodelling-tool wwwsqldesigner. It contains all tables, their comments, columns and their datatypes, primary key columns and so on.

I imported the xml file in my php script successfully with simplexml_load_file and now I want to loop through the nodes/tags to get 3 lists (to insert them into a database in 3 tables afterwards, for the moment echoing is enough).

Those lists are:
1) Tables: Tablenames in the datamodel/xml-file, their comments and primary key names.
2) Columns: The columns of that tables: columnname, datatype, nullable (and column order if possible).
3) Primary Key Columns: columnname and column order.

The xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<sql>
<table x="673" y="237" name="DIM_CUSTOMER">
<row name="CUSTOMER_SID" null="0" autoincrement="1">
<datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
<default>NULL</default><comment>Customer-SK</comment>
</row>
<row name="CUSTOMER_NAME" null="0" autoincrement="0">
<datatype>VARCHAR(30)</datatype>
<default>'NULL'</default><comment>Customername</comment>
</row>
<row name="CUSTOMER_GROUP" null="1" autoincrement="0">
<datatype>VARCHAR(30)</datatype>
<default>NULL</default></row>
<key type="PRIMARY" name="DIM_CUSTOMER_PK">
<part>CUSTOMER_SID</part>
</key>
<comment>Kunden</comment>
</table>
<table x="1150" y="204" name="DIM_PRODUCT">
<row name="PRODUCT_SID" null="0" autoincrement="1">
<datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
<default>NULL</default><comment>Produkt-Sk</comment>
</row>
<row name="PRODUCT_NAME" null="0" autoincrement="0">
<datatype>VARCHAR(30)</datatype>
<default>'NULL'</default><comment>Productname</comment>
</row>
<key type="PRIMARY" name="DIM_PRODUCT_PK">
<part>PRODUCT_SID</part>
</key>
<comment>Product</comment>
</table>
<table x="632" y="499" name="DIM_DATE">
<row name="DATE_ID" null="0" autoincrement="1">
<datatype>DATE</datatype>
<default>'NULL'</default></row>
<row name="YEAR" null="1" autoincrement="0">
<datatype>CHAR(4)</datatype>
<default>NULL</default></row>
<row name="QUARTER" null="1" autoincrement="0">
<datatype>CHAR(2)</datatype>
<default>NULL</default></row>
<row name="MONTH" null="1" autoincrement="0">
<datatype>VARCHAR(2)</datatype>
<default>NULL</default></row>
<key type="PRIMARY" name="DIM_DATE_PK">
<part>DATE_ID</part>
</key>
</table>
<table x="1214" y="511" name="DIM_INVENTORY">
<row name="INVENTORY_SID" null="1" autoincrement="1">
<datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
<default>NULL</default><comment>Inventory SK</comment>
</row>
<row name="INVENTORY_NAME" null="0" autoincrement="0">
<datatype>VARCHAR(30)</datatype>
<default>'NULL'</default><comment>Inventory</comment>
</row>
<key type="PRIMARY" name="DIM_DATE_PK">
<part>INVENTORY_SID</part>
</key>
</table>
<table x="950" y="358" name="FACT_SALES">
<row name="DATE_ID" null="0" autoincrement="0">
<datatype>DATE</datatype>
<default>'NULL'</default><relation table="DIM_DATE" row="DATE_ID" />
</row>
<row name="INVENTORY_SID" null="1" autoincrement="0">
<datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
<default>NULL</default><relation table="DIM_INVENTORY" row="INVENTORY_SID" />
<comment>Inventory SK</comment>
</row>
<row name="PRODUCT_SID" null="0" autoincrement="0">
<datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
<default>NULL</default><relation table="DIM_PRODUCT" row="PRODUCT_SID" />
<comment>Product-Sk</comment>
</row>
<row name="CUSTOMER_SID" null="0" autoincrement="0">
<datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
<default>NULL</default><relation table="DIM_CUSTOMER" row="CUSTOMER_SID" />
<comment>Customer-SK</comment>
</row>
<row name="REVENUE" null="0" autoincrement="0">
<datatype>DECIMAL(10,2)</datatype>
<default>NULL</default></row>
<key type="PRIMARY" name="FACT_SALES_PK">
<part>DATE_ID</part>
<part>INVENTORY_SID</part>
<part>PRODUCT_SID</part>
<part>CUSTOMER_SID</part>
</key>
<comment>Sales</comment>
</table>
</sql>
```

For each database table there is a  tag that contains several  tags and a  tag for the primary key and a  tag. The  tag itself has several  tags for every primary key columns.

To create the 3 needed lists mentioned above I wrote follwing php script:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('C:\xampp\htdocs\sqldesigner\backend\php-mysql\Datamart.xml');

// Tables
echo "+++++++++++++ TABLES +++++++++++++<br>";
foreach ($xml->table as $table) {
        echo "----------------------------------------<br>";
        echo "Tabelle: "  . $table['name']  . "<br>"; //Tabelle
        echo "Primary: "  . $table->key['name']     . "<br>"; //PK
        echo "Comment: "  . $table->comment     . "<br>"; //Table-Comment       

}
// Columns
echo "+++++++++++++ COLUMNS +++++++++++++<br>";
foreach ($xml->table as $table) {

        foreach ($table as $row) {
            echo "Column: "   . $table['name'] . "." . $row['name'] . "<br>";
            echo "Nullable: " . $row["null"]    . "<br>";
            echo "Datatype: " . $row->datatype."<br>";
            echo "Comment: "  . $row->comment . "<br>"; 
            echo "---------------------<br>";
        }           
}

// PK-Columns
echo "+++++++++++++ PRIMARY KEY COLS +++++++++++++<br>";
foreach ($xml->table as $table) {

        foreach ($table as $primarykey) {
            echo "PK-Col.: " . $table['name'] . "." . $primarykey->part . "<br>";

        }
}
?>
```

Unfortunately the output is wrong for columns and primary keys. It produces empty lines. So my guess is, there is a connection from the inner foreach to the outer foreach missing. The output looks like this:

```
+++++++++++++ TABLES +++++++++++++
----------------------------------------
Tabelle: DIM_CUSTOMER
Primary: DIM_CUSTOMER_PK
Comment: Kunden
----------------------------------------
Tabelle: DIM_PRODUCT
Primary: DIM_PRODUCT_PK
Comment: Product
----------------------------------------
Tabelle: DIM_DATE
Primary: DIM_DATE_PK
Comment: 
----------------------------------------
Tabelle: DIM_INVENTORY
Primary: DIM_DATE_PK
Comment: 
----------------------------------------
Tabelle: FACT_SALES
Primary: FACT_SALES_PK
Comment: Sales
+++++++++++++ COLUMNS +++++++++++++
Column: DIM_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_SID
Nullable: 0
Datatype: INTEGER
Comment: Customer-SK
---------------------
Column: DIM_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME
Nullable: 0
Datatype: VARCHAR(30)
Comment: Customername
---------------------
Column: DIM_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_GROUP
Nullable: 1
Datatype: VARCHAR(30)
Comment: 
---------------------
Column: DIM_CUSTOMER.DIM_CUSTOMER_PK
Nullable: 
Datatype: 
Comment: 
---------------------
Column: DIM_CUSTOMER.
Nullable: 
Datatype: 
Comment: 
---------------------
Column: DIM_PRODUCT.PRODUCT_SID
Nullable: 0
Datatype: INTEGER
Comment: Produkt-Sk
---------------------
Column: DIM_PRODUCT.PRODUCT_NAME
Nullable: 0
Datatype: VARCHAR(30)
Comment: Productname
---------------------
Column: DIM_PRODUCT.DIM_PRODUCT_PK
Nullable: 
Datatype: 
Comment: 
---------------------
Column: DIM_PRODUCT.
Nullable: 
Datatype: 
Comment: 
---------------------
Column: DIM_DATE.DATE_ID
Nullable: 0
Datatype: DATE
Comment: 
---------------------
Column: DIM_DATE.YEAR
Nullable: 1
Datatype: CHAR(4)
Comment: 
---------------------
Column: DIM_DATE.QUARTER
Nullable: 1
Datatype: CHAR(2)
Comment: 
---------------------
Column: DIM_DATE.MONTH
Nullable: 1
Datatype: VARCHAR(2)
Comment: 
---------------------
Column: DIM_DATE.DIM_DATE_PK
Nullable: 
Datatype: 
Comment: 
---------------------
Column: DIM_INVENTORY.INVENTORY_SID
Nullable: 1
Datatype: INTEGER
Comment: Inventory SK
---------------------
Column: DIM_INVENTORY.INVENTORY_NAME
Nullable: 0
Datatype: VARCHAR(30)
Comment: Inventory
---------------------
Column: DIM_INVENTORY.DIM_DATE_PK
Nullable: 
Datatype: 
Comment: 
---------------------
Column: FACT_SALES.DATE_ID
Nullable: 0
Datatype: DATE
Comment: 
---------------------
Column: FACT_SALES.INVENTORY_SID
Nullable: 1
Datatype: INTEGER
Comment: Inventory SK
---------------------
Column: FACT_SALES.PRODUCT_SID
Nullable: 0
Datatype: INTEGER
Comment: Product-Sk
---------------------
Column: FACT_SALES.CUSTOMER_SID
Nullable: 0
Datatype: INTEGER
Comment: Customer-SK
---------------------
Column: FACT_SALES.REVENUE
Nullable: 0
Datatype: DECIMAL(10,2)
Comment: 
---------------------
Column: FACT_SALES.FACT_SALES_PK
Nullable: 
Datatype: 
Comment: 
---------------------
Column: FACT_SALES.
Nullable: 
Datatype: 
Comment: 
---------------------
+++++++++++++ PRIMARY KEY COLS +++++++++++++
PK-Col.: DIM_CUSTOMER.
PK-Col.: DIM_CUSTOMER.
PK-Col.: DIM_CUSTOMER.
PK-Col.: DIM_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_SID
PK-Col.: DIM_CUSTOMER.
PK-Col.: DIM_PRODUCT.
PK-Col.: DIM_PRODUCT.
PK-Col.: DIM_PRODUCT.PRODUCT_SID
PK-Col.: DIM_PRODUCT.
PK-Col.: DIM_DATE.
PK-Col.: DIM_DATE.
PK-Col.: DIM_DATE.
PK-Col.: DIM_DATE.
PK-Col.: DIM_DATE.DATE_ID
PK-Col.: DIM_INVENTORY.
PK-Col.: DIM_INVENTORY.
PK-Col.: DIM_INVENTORY.INVENTORY_SID
PK-Col.: FACT_SALES.
PK-Col.: FACT_SALES.
PK-Col.: FACT_SALES.
PK-Col.: FACT_SALES.
PK-Col.: FACT_SALES.
PK-Col.: FACT_SALES.DATE_ID
PK-Col.: FACT_SALES.
```

[Here is how the datamodel from the xml looks like in the wwwsqldesigner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOQo2.png)

Any suggestions how to handle this problem?

Thank you and cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats happening because you're iterating through all table nodes without filtering, try the following solution:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('C:\xampp\htdocs\sqldesigner\backend\php-mysql\Datamart.xml');

// Tables
echo "+++++++++++++ TABLES +++++++++++++<br>";
foreach ($xml->table as $table) {
        echo "----------------------------------------<br>";
        echo "Tabelle: "  . $table['name']  . "<br>"; //Tabelle
        echo "Primary: "  . $table->key['name']     . "<br>"; //PK
        echo "Comment: "  . $table->comment     . "<br>"; //Table-Comment

}
// Columns
echo "+++++++++++++ COLUMNS +++++++++++++<br>";
foreach ($xml->table as $table) {

        foreach ($table as $row) {
            if ($row->getName() != 'row') {
                continue;
            }

            echo "Column: "   . $table['name'] . "." . $row['name'] . "<br>";
            echo "Nullable: " . $row["null"]    . "<br>";
            echo "Datatype: " . $row->datatype."<br>";
            echo "Comment: "  . $row->comment . "<br>";
            echo "---------------------<br>";
        }
}

// PK-Columns
echo "+++++++++++++ PRIMARY KEY COLS +++++++++++++<br>";
foreach ($xml->table as $table) {

        foreach ($table as $primarykey) {
            if ($primarykey->getName() != 'key') {
                continue;
            }

            echo "PK-Col.: " . $table['name'] . "." . $primarykey->part . "<br>";

        }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same way that you use `$xml->table` in your outer loop, you also need to get the inner loop to just select the `<row>` elements.

So your inner foreach loop becomes..

```
foreach ($table->row as $row) {
```

As you can see, your picking up all the subelements of `<table>`, this will limit it to just the `<row>` ones.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn´t get that working. I´ve tried that before.